# Eloquent not adding automatically s at the end of table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a Lumen app.
I just created a new TillSoftware model with this migration file

```
Schema::create('till_softwares', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string("name", 120);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But when I just run a simple request like this

```
$softwareList = TillSoftware::all();
```

I receive an error telling

```
Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.till_software' doesn't exist
```

It doesn't seem to add the usual extra s at the end of the table name and trying to make a request to till_software instead of till_softwares.
I have more than 20 other models which aren't running just fine, and as far as I know plural of software is softwares.

Am I missing something obvious here?
I still can add an extra

```
protected $table = 'till_softwares';
```

on my model but I would prefer to understand what I did incorrectly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you configure database name properly?

Comment: Yes I did. All the other controllers from the app are running just fine.

Comment: Since "software" is uncountable, Laravel look for "till_software".

Comment: What do you mean uncountable? I can have many softwares.
But I guess you're probably right I think there is probably something weird here but I can't understand why I couldn't have multiple softwares.

Comment: @Fabrice I'm not making the rules of the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So laravel will use `Str::plural()` to find the plural of the model name to find the table name as this is standard.

```
>>> Str::plural('user')
=> "users"
```

So this is `User` model into `users` table

```
>>> Str::plural('software')
=> "software"
```

but the plural of software is software, so that is the table name.

If you want to use softwares you will need to do as you said

```
protected $table = 'till_softwares';
```

But I would say that using the standard table names would be best, so it should be `till_software`

Comment: OK, english isn't my mother name, so I may miss something here, but I think I saw several times the word softwares. Is this sentence wrong : "I am using 3 different softwares" on y computer?

Comment: Yeah, so "softwares" is not a word in the english language. You would instead adjust the wording so say "I am using 3 different pieces of software.".

Comment: Ah ah OK I get it. I guess I learned something on the english language rather some code today :D